# Book series: apocalyptic event - magic stops working so people create technology (or vice versa)

Tags: story-identification, novel

I came across some fan art from a book series that sounded really conceptually interesting. I can't find it again.

An event happened which made all magic suddenly stop working so people ended up creating technology to fill their needs instead. It might be the other way around, I'm not sure.

The piece of art was, I believe, a ranger type character with an odd looking bow. I believe it was someone's RPG character based on this setting. The art looked quite light in tone, I.E. not grim.

Comment: There are a lot of works about either magic coming after technology, or technology after magic.  Do you have any more details about the art?  The questions at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried to add some details

Comment: Do you still have a link to the image, perchance? If not, do you remember what was different about the boys? Shape? Material? Didn't guys coming off of it?

Comment: No, it's not that. The more I think about it, the more I think it's technology->magic rather than the other way round.

Comment: The bow would suggest living in a world where firearms aren't reliable, so I'd guess it wasn't magic failing permanently and technology developing.  That means it could be technology to magic, or back-and-forth shifts like the Ilona Andrews series kamskywalker mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to just comment, but since I only just made an account, here's an answer instead.

This sounds a lot like the world in [Ilona Andrews Kate Daniels series](http://www.ilona-andrews.com/kate-daniels/)

Basic premise is that humanity pushed technology too far, and magic came in and wiped out technology. Now the world shifts back and forth between tech and magic.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest.  The "technological civilization giving way to magic " with a post-apocalyptic feel is spot on, although the main character is a mercenary swordswoman rather than a ranger, and there are no unusual bows mentioned in the series, and I wouldn't consider the art to be 'light'

Comment: @ArcanistLupus I didn't put too much stock in the ranger description since OP states it was probably an RPG character based on the fantasy setting, and not official art from the series (such as book covers).